# Regular expression to get a group of text

Tags: regex

I cant find the right regular expression:

```
print(re.compile(r'row_([0-9]+)(_[^_]+)*').split('row_0007_id_testa_testb'))
> ['', '0007', '_testb', '']
```

I tried with non-greedy regexp, didn't work too:

```
print(re.compile(r'row_([0-9]+)(_[^_]+)+?').split('row_0007_id_testa_testb'))
['', '0007', '_id', '_testa_testb']
```

I need to get this:

```
> ['', '0007', 'id', 'testa', 'testb']
```

Comment: Where is `__monitoring` in your string?

Comment: @revo updated my question sorry

Comment: Try `re.compile(r'row_|_').split('row_0007_id_testa_testb')`

Comment: Do you need the first empty entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple regex `_([^_]+)` in `findall` with an inline if condition to assert that string starts with `row_`:

```
>>> reg = re.compile(r'_([^_]+)')

>>> s = 'row_0007_id_testa_testb'
>>> print re.findall(reg, s) if s.startswith('row_') else None
['0007', 'id', 'testa', 'testb']

>>> s = 'col_0007_id_testa_testb'
>>> print re.findall(reg, s) if s.startswith('row_') else None
None
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to match strings that contains letters and numbers only, but replace the first match with an empty string. If so, use

```
re.compile(r'^[^\W_]+_+|[\W_]+').split('row_0007_id_testa_testb')
```

Output:

> ```
> ['', '0007', 'id', 'testa', 'testb']
> ```

Test this code [here](https://ideone.com/bLoxyz).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using a single `re.split` command:

```
re.split(r"^row_|_", "row_0007_id_testa_testb)
```

For a more generalized replace:

```
re.split(r"^[a-z]+_|_", "row_0007_id_testa_testb")
```

This would eliminate the first word characters preceded by the first `_` and then split the rest.

It's unclear by the question, although if looking to prepend the split string list this should work:

```
r = re.split(r"_", s)[1:]
r.insert(0,'')
```

Comment: I believe he doesn't want to eliminate the first word,... he wants the first match to be an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You did't indicate the host programming language, but I assume
it is Python.

As I see, you want to split the source text on `_` character, so
just `_` should be the content of the regex.

```
p = re.compile('_').split('row_0007_id_testa_testb')
```

gives sets `['row', '0007', 'id', 'testa', 'testb']` in `p`.

So the only thing to change is to set the starting element to an
empty string. Then you can print the `p` array, getting the
expected result.

Below you have the example script:

```
import re
p = re.compile('_').split('row_0007_id_testa_testb')
print p
p[0] = ''
print p
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an alternation `|` with `findall`, which would match `row_` and capture not an underscore in a capturing group `([^_]+)`

[`row_|([^_]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/rkknFB/1)

```
import re
print(re.findall(r"row_|([^_]+)", 'row_0007_id_testa_testb'))
```

That would give you:

```
['', '0007', 'id', 'testa', 'testb']
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/FXD54645)